# Are one sided limits sometimes pointless?

Tags: limits

For example if $f (x)=\sqrt x$ and we're trying to find the limit of $f (x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ from left.Isn't that useless?

Comment: In this case, the function isn't even defined to the left of 0.I don't think the limit is even defined in this case. If, under some definitions, it is defined, it's not a useful concept.

Comment: Using complex numbers, it's still $0$.

Comment: Similar to asking what $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$ is for the finite sequence given by $\,a_n = n^2\;$ for $\,n \,= \,1, \,2,\, 3,\, 4.$

Comment: No mathematics is pointless :-)

Comment: As with many things, context matters. Why would you be considering this particular one-sided limit? Say specifically what you were looking for and why, and then we can argue about whether that particular effort is pointless _for that purpose._

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call them pointless, rather, that they don't make sense logically.

As Jordan mentioned, $\sqrt{x}$ only exists for nonnegative $x$ so there is no limit to the left because $\sqrt{0-\epsilon}$ doesn't exist.

In this case, the limit you would  want to use the right-hand limit. Perhaps a pointless limit would be a limit from a side where the function does not exhibit the needed properties: such as accidentally evaluating $\lfloor x\rfloor$ from the left instead of the right.

Comment: I would say that evaluating the limit of $\lfloor x\rfloor$ from the left is very informative. Among other things, it lets us know the function is not continuous. I think it’s at least as interesting as the right-hand limit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case. I wouldn't say it's pointless -it is simply sometimes not defined, and it isn't a reason to make a conclusion that it is pointless.